# inequality and logic

Tags: inequality

$|x-2|-|x+4| > 2 $

So I have to check for a. $x\leq -4$ b.$-4<x\leq2$ c.$x>2$

for a.$x\leq -4$ it is $-(x-2)--(x+4)>2\rightarrow -x+2+x+4>2\rightarrow 0x>-4$

 so it is $x\leq -4$ and all x = $x\leq -4$

for b.$-4<x\leq2$ it is $-(x-2)-(x+4)>2\rightarrow -x+2-x-4>2\rightarrow -2x>4\rightarrow x<-2$
so it is $-4<x\leq2$ and $x<-2$= $-4<x\leq2$=$-4<x\leq2$

for c.$x>2$ it is $(x-2)-(x+4)>2\rightarrow x-2-x-4>2 \rightarrow 0x>8 $
so it is not such x and $x>2$= not such x

so it is overall $x\leq -4$ or $-4<x\leq2$ = $x \leq 2$

but the answer is $x \leq -2$ where have I got it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple mistake. $−4<x≤2$ and $x<−2$ means $-4 < x < -2$, not $-4 < x ≤ 2$.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have it much wrong till the last step.  If you combine the two regions $x \leq -4$ and $-4 < x \leq -2$ you get the single region $x \leq -2$.  So your answer matches the answer given.

Which, however, is itself wrong!  The correct answer is $x < -2$.

$x = -2$ would give 
$$
4 - 2 > 2
$$
which is not correct.

And your logic in the second region does have $x < -2$; you just seem to drop that condition.

Answer (score 1):

In (b) you reached "$-4\lt x \leq2$ and $x \lt -2$".  This implies  $-4\lt x \lt -2$.

Combine this with (a)'s alternative possibility of $x \le -4$ and you get $x \lt -2$ overall.